# 100% height div inside 100% td

Tags: html

Ok,
so here is my problem.. and its buggin me for a while... 
i need to set the following DIV 100% height inside this TD without any side-effects (by that i mean scrolling), because for some unknown reason, when i set it to 100% height, looks like IE 8 does some wrong calculations..
I tried a lot of combinations but no success..
transitional doctype is required...
thanks in advance for any help!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<style>
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
</style>
<head>
    <body>
        <table style="height:100%" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>TOP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:100%">
                <td style="height:100%">
                    <div style="border:1px dotted blue; height:100%">CONTENT</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ... are you using tables for layout of non-tabular data? ...

Comment: @jball: Man, I stopped fighting that fight a long time ago.  The battle is just too uphill.  Also, the mix of header styling and inline styling is a little unsettling as well.

Comment: well, guys, i dont have a choice its an old layout, and i need that div 100% height, and i cant remove the tables at the moment..

Comment: @jball: feel free to change the div for another table, the bug is in 100% height with any element, the div is just for a presentation purpose

Comment: @Brizio, can I ask why you need any element inside that <td> at all?? you can style the <td> perfectly fine with css...

Comment: its an old system.. Everything is based on td and tr. its an old menu that uses the 100% height to show other content inside that td,

Comment: so couldnt you either remove the div, or just let the div fill out as it needs??? is there a working example of the menu?

Comment: @Brizio I've been there, working within broken constraints. You might want to try pointing out to the person that is asking you to add the doctype line that this task is at odds with the requirement to keep the existing tables for layout.

Comment: @Brizio hacky jquery answer below... best i can do :)

Answer (score 1):

<del>The border on the div is 'external' to the height... So really, the style you are applying is a height of 100% + 2px (1px top border, 1px bottom border)...



If you remove the border the true height will be 100% and the scroll bar should disappear :)



As commented below, the `height:100%` in the bottom cell makes the total table height = first row height + the 100% of the bottom row height.</del>

**UPDATE:** okay, so its not pretty, but its the best i've got:

if you were to give the div an id of `blah` and use the following jquery to hack the height of the div to that of it's parents... this does require a height definition for the first row/cell though.. i set at 100px for an example.

```
$('#blah').height($('#blah').parent().height());
```

jsfiddle example... http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/vwcvN/

Comment: the border is just for orientation, create a html document with that code and you will see it on IE8, the exact scroll size is the TOP TD height

Comment: yes, because the height:100% is in the cell on the bottom row.  the total height of the table is first row height + second row height. because the second row height is 100% the total height is first row height + 100%

Comment: i already got that, but what i want is to the bottom cell/row to use the remaining height left from the first row

Comment: just for a test, if you remove the doctype line, everything works... but unfortunely thats my job, to PUT that god damn line =/

Comment: when i removed the doctype line it was still broken :S

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the foundations of the css box models. For example: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html