# Div 100% height in <td>

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

Related question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514806/100-height-div-inside-100-td), but it's not really helpful as I can't explicitly set the height of anything, all of it has variable user defined content that can be one line tall or 5 lines tall.

Bit stuck on this one, given a table (inline CSS is for demonstration only):

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="background:red">
                        Something here<br />
                        More
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="border:1px solid green">This needs to be 100% remaining height</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td style="background:blue">
            Blah<br />
            Blah<br />
            Blah<br />
            Blah<br />
            Blah<br />
            Variable<br />
            Number<br />
            Of lines!
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to make the div expand to 100% height of it's containing div, so it matches the total height of the `blah blah blah` column (and for this to happen I assume the parent td first needs to expand to fill remaining height).

I have a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/WZC35/1/

Showing what I mean a lot clearer.

I can use Jquery, but would rather have a CSS solution.  **I know that using tables is questionable** but this is for a Jquery plugin to render data in a fairly complicated layout, and tables provide the best supported solution and solve a lot of alignment issues, if you want to see this context of it, see this link:

http://69.24.73.172/demos/eventml/default.htm

I'm trying to make the big purple purple box match the height of the right hand column.

Comment: a table within a table ? I mean I hate using tables altogether, but a table within a table? hmmm It just not very SEO friendly, and alot slower than it should be

Comment: I imagine you can't use rowspan instead of nested tables?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WZC35/11/ .... basically you must specify the parent height, for the child to have a 100% height. otherwise it would not know what height to follow 100% of what?

Comment: @Val, I can't use any explicit heights, it has to expand with the blue column but thanks for looking.

Comment: First of all your nested table has to be as high as the `td` where it is in. This is at all not possible because the table measures the hight automatic except you set fixed values.

Comment: @Val it has to be nested because of the design of the display, look at the last link I provided for context.

Comment: you do the maths @tom you have `100 % of X = ?` another way is that you could insert a table and specify it's height, http://jsfiddle.net/WZC35/14/ otherwise I don't know how you could make it happen, unless u look into css expressions :) or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After take a look to your links, I think that you could use perfectly rowspan instead of nested tables (like says PJP). Then you can associate the CSS decoration desired (purple background) to the td, not to the div. The div could only contains text, if it is needed at all.

```
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="background:red">
                        Something here<br />
                        More
        </td>
        <td style="background:blue" rowspan="2">
            Blah<br />
            Blah<br />
            Blah<br />
            Blah<br />
            Blah
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid green">
            <div >This needs to be 100% height</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't really help as the contained div needs to be styled (it has rounded corners for example and is only 80% width, see the last link I posted.) so the div has to be 100% height of it's container.

Answer (score 1):

I cant say I like anything about this markup.  Nested tables are ugly and inline styles are problematic too but This seems to get close to what you want?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Something here More</title>
</head>

<body>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td valign="top" style="height: 100%">
    <table style="height:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="background: red;">Something here<br />
            More </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:100%">
            <td style="height:100%">
            <div style="border: 1px solid green; height:100%">
                This needs to be 100% remaining height</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <td style="background: blue">Blah<br />
    Blah<br />
    Blah<br />
    Blah<br />
    Blah<br />
    Variable<br />
    Number<br />
    Of lines! </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: If you can programatically create your table you can set the TD that holds the nested table to have colspan of the number of columns left in the preceding table.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but it still seems to produce the same results: http://jsfiddle.net/w56c7/ , you are right though, the tables are programatically generated so the number of cols/rows is known.